# Secure PHP Login Script

Tags: php

I am using following code lines in order to protect injections or the like for login via PHP script. Kindly let me know will it be enough to be safe from the attack or I have to add some more lines to make the code more secured.

```
// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$username = stripslashes($username);
$password = stripslashes($password);
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);
```

Comment: Not using `mysql_*` at all would be a start.

Comment: PDO: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php. Tutorial: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/php-database-access-are-you-doing-it-correctly/

Comment: Like @BenFortune say, no `mysql_*` functions. Also, are you saving plain passwords?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory that should be safe enough, however there are still several problems with it.

1. mysql_real_escape_string is deprecated - you should not use them, but a prepared statement.
2. You are not hashing the password - it is not a good idea to store plain text passwords, as if the database is compromised, they will all be immediately known. PHP has a dedicated [password_hash](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function which you can use instead.
3. Why are you stripping slashes? If you are expecting the input username might contain slashes, then you are missing a validation step somewhere else. In general, it is better to use whitelists than blacklists - i.e. instead of trying to strip out bad characters, have a list of good characters and only allow those. That way you can secure your username/password with something simple, like `preg_replace('#[^a-bA-B0-9]#', '', $username)`

Answer (score 3):

Using any `mysql_*` functions is not entirely secure. That family of functions is now deprecated.

You should look at using [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) with prepared statements for the absolute security...

Comment: Thanks for quick response I am using MySQLi and before sending the variables to my php SQL query, I am using above mentioned lines from my code. So will it be enough in that case?

Comment: The best practice here is to use prepared statements, as I said above, and avoid outdated functions altogether.

Answer (score 0):

If you know what you are doing, mysql_* functions are still good to use, though they have been deprecated. Just be sure you don't let in a injection vulnerability. mysql_* functions are deprectated because it is too easy to let such vulnerabilities in. Other function libraries such as mysqli_* and PDO_* allow for parameterized queries, that makes it easier to write secure code.

Be aware off course that you have absolutely no guarantee that deprecated functions will still exist in newer versions of PHP.

They lines you stated are too much. Only `mysql_real_escape_string()` is needed. You can remove `strip_slashes()`.

Comment: **Do not recommend the use of deprecated functions in new code.** Even if someone know what they're doing with them - that's the definition of deprecation.

Comment: Why you say to not use the `mysql_*` functions and say that `mysql_real_escape_string` is OK?

Comment: Huh? I didn't say that at all?